# How do I disable graph mode in Assembly view in IDA 6.1?

Tags: ida

How do I disable graph mode in Assembly view in IDA 6.1 ? By graph mode I mean this

[image]

I see Options -> Graph -> Use graph view by default, but un-checking it doesn't help :((

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To toggle graph view in addresses where graph view is applicable, **hit the space key**.  (Or, as ruslan mentioned, you can right-click the disassembly area and choose "Text View")

The option you mentioned (Options -> Graph -> Use graph view by default) specifies that graph view will not be enabled when you open a new binary for analysis.  This has no effect on the current view in the database.

By the way, if the reason you don't want to use graph view is because it doesn't display the address of each instruction, you can change this by going into the options, clicking the "Disassembly" tab, and checking "Line Prefixes" under "Display disassembly line parts."

Answer (score 3):

Ah, it's right click on Assembly area and choosing "Text view".

It should have been more obvious.